# Doxygen combine .c and .h to one module

Tags: c, doxygen

i'm trying to get a useful doxygen for my C project. The thing is that I only get a file list showing all .h and all .c files.

But what I want is a Module view where the .h and the .c files are combined. Somewhat like a C++ Class with all the functions and variable named in the .h file shown as public and all the additional functions and variables inside the .c as private.

Is there any way to do that.

eg. the header file:

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H_
#define DISPLAY_H_

#include <compiler.h>

void display_init();

void display_off();
void display_set(uint16_t value);

#endif /* DISPLAY_H_ */
```

and the C file

```
#include "display.h"
 
uint8_t state;

void green();
void orange();

void display_init()
{
    ...
}

void display_off()
{
    ...
}

void display_set(uint16_t value)
{
    ...
}

void green()
{
    ...
}

void orange()
{
    ...
}
```

So now in the doxygen there should only be one page for the module `display`.

I hope my question it is clear ;)
Thanks

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you have a look at the grouping commands like `\defgroup` etc.?

Comment: `So now in the doxygen there should only be one page for the module display` Why? How should doxygen know that "there should be one page" for "the module display"?